# "profound" vs. "extensive"

Tags: word-usage

I am preparing for the IELTS. So I am learning to use high-level words as much as possible.

Consider this

> the infrastructure for e-commerce is so **extensive** that almost everything I need in everyday life can now be had at the tip of your fingers
>   with a click

Does this one pretty much mean the same thing?

> the infrastructure for e-commerce is so **profound** that ...

the word "profound" is a synonym for "extensive", though [the Meaning of profound on Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/profound) seems more about feelings.

> felt or experienced very strongly or in an extreme way

Comment: This is purely a matter of whether you want to use a two-dimensional ***surface*** metaphor or a three-dimensional ***depth*** metaphor. There's no other significance.

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica I know what two-dimensional and three-dimensional are, I don't understand **two-dimensional surface metaphor** though. [Google](https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C5CHFA_enUS706US706&ei=KabbXq-hCa3VmAW4gInQCQ&q=two-dimensional+surface+metaphor&oq=two-dimensional+surface+metaphor&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQAzIECAAQRzIECAAQRzIECAAQRzIECAAQRzIECAAQRzIECAAQRzIECAAQRzIECAAQR1DLtbwBWMu1vAFg07e8AWgAcAN4AIABAIgBAJIBAJgBAKABAqABAaoBB2d3cy13aXo&sclient=psy-ab&ved=0ahUKEwjv2aWhse3pAhWtKqYKHThAApoQ4dUDCAw&uact=5) doesn't understand that either, would you please explain a bit more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sentence describes the easy access to goods that results from how widespread (extensive) e-commerce is. The word "profound" doesn't fit well as an adjective for "infrastructure", but it could describe its effects, for example,

> E-commerce infrastructure has **profound** effects on the way business is conducted.

So, "extensive" is better to describe the state of something, while "profound" is better to describe effects or influence, or changes that have resulted.

(You didn't ask about this, but the switch in perspective between "everything **I** need" and "the tip of **your** fingers" is a little jarring. You might want to stay with either "I/my" or "you/your".)